# Custom learning rate decay with tensors, lambdas, and python variable binding

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to build a custom TensorFlow estimator and train it.

I would like to be able to modify its behavior through extra parameters. Specifically, to set the optimizer, and specify a formula for the learning rate that depends on the epoch.

So for example, ideally, I would be able to do this:

```
model = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    params={
    ...
    "optimizer": tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(
        learning_rate=0.001 * tf.train.global_step()**(-0.75),
        momentum=0.5
        ),
    ...
    }
)
model.train()
```

How would I go about it?

#### What I know now

After some poking around, it became obvious to me that the above approach isn't going to work, because `tf.train.global_step()` depends on having a session, and I don't have a session at least until I call `model.train()`.

I also know that there might be some kind of witchcraft that lets me defer the call to `tf.train.global_step()` until model_fn is actually run my `tf.Estimator`.

I'm just at loss at how the whole thing works together, and would appreciate some help for
1. Solving this problem
2. Understanding how variable binding works
3. Understand how `tf.train.global_step()` fetches the tensor object, and what a tensor really is.

#### Possible Duplicates

- [tensorflow: use py_func to define custom learning rate decay before applied to optimizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196738/tensorflow-use-py-func-to-define-custom-learning-rate-decay-before-applied-to-o)
  This guy is messin' with custom optimizers. I don't want get into that.
- [TensorFlow: How to set learning rate decay based on epochs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899939/tensorflow-how-to-set-learning-rate-decay-based-on-epochs)
  I don't care about epochs.
- [TensorFlow learning rate decay - how to properly supply the step number for decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297193/tensorflow-learning-rate-decay-how-to-properly-supply-the-step-number-for-deca)
  This looks like what I wish I could do, but I don't know how to translate it to the language of `tf.Estimators`.